# Memory Management - Multiple Buttons and retaincount

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

i´ve created my own scrollView and added different Buttons on that View. This class `MyScrollView` was created on a ViewController. Then i´ve tested that on the iOS simulator while calling the "simulate memory warning". But nothing happens - no dealloc on that `MyScrollView` is called. So i´ve checked the retaincount on different code lines.

Unfortunately, all the apple memory docu and different cocoa blogs didn´t help me. 
So it would be cool if some of you devs could help me on that..

**MyScrollView.h**

```
@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView { 

    NSArray* photosThumb;
    NSArray* photosFull;
    NSMutableArray* photoItemsArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* photosThumb;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* photosFull;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* photoItemsArray;

@end
```

**MyScrollView.m**

```
@implementation MyScrollView

@synthesize photoItemsArray, photosFull, photosThumb;

-(id) initArraySmall:(NSArray*) _photos  
        initArrayBig:(NSArray*) _photosBig{

        self.photosThumb = _photos;
        self.photosFull =  _photosBig;

        NSUInteger i, count = [self.photosThumb count];

        self.photoItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {       
            MyButton* photoButton = [[MyButton alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"MyButton 1: %d", [photoButton retainCount]); // -> 1

            [photoButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(buttonDown: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        

            [self.photoItemsArray addObject:photoButton];
            NSLog(@"MyButton 2: %d", [photoButton retainCount]); // -> 2

            [photoButton release];
            NSLog(@"MyButton 3: %d", [photoButton retainCount]); // -> 1

            [self addSubview:[self.photoItemsArray lastObject]];   
            NSLog(@"MyButton 4: %d", [photoButton retainCount]); // -> 2
        }

        [self.photosThumb retain];
        [self.photosFull retain];
        NSLog(@"photosThumb: %d photosFull: %d", [photosThumb retainCount], [photosFull retainCount]); // -> retaincount 4, 0


        [self.photoItemsArray release];
        NSLog(@"photoItemsArray 1: %d", [self.photoItemsArray retainCount]); // -> 1


    }
    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");

    self.photosThumb = nil; 
    self.photosFull = nil;
    self.photoItemsArray = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**Here´s my ViewController.h**

```
@interface VideoViewController : UIViewController {
    MyScrollView* myView;
    NSArray* photos;
    NSArray* photosBig;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyScrollView* myView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* photos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* photosBig;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one.png", @"two.png", @"three.png", nil];
photosBig = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"oneBig.png", @"twoBig.png", @"threeBig.png", nil];

self.myView = [[MyScrollView alloc] initArraySmall:photos initArrayBig:photosBig];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myView];
    [self.myView release];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveMemoryWarning");
    [self.myView release];
     self.myView = nil; 
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
     NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [self.photos release];
    [self.photosBig release];   
    [self.photoGallery release];
}
```

Comment: Why you are not releasing photoButton inside the loop???

Comment: @makboney: i release it before that line: "NSLog(@"MyButton 3: %d", [photoButton retainCount]); // -> 1

Comment: upps sorry...didn't notice that...one more question why are you releasing photoItemsArray???

Comment: makboney: `photoItemsArray` is retained when it is created. It must be released otherwise there will be a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the dealloc method. 
Setting **photosThumb**, **photosFull**, and **photoItemArray** as **nil** do not deallocate the objects. Since, you add custom Button to the arrays, you must make sure that each of your custom are properly deallocated.

```
   - (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");

    self.photosThumb = nil; 
    self.photosFull = nil;
    self.photoItemsArray = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Hi Dimitri, thx for your fast reply. I´ve also tested that. No dealloc is called. What about the view of the MyScrollView-class? All the buttons are retained in that. So do i have to clean something in it?

Comment: You should never call `dealloc` directly. Allow the memory-management system to do this by correctly using retain/release. Setting those properties to `nil` **will** release them, so this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyScrollView` is likely still retained by the superview, window, responder chain, etcetera. In your `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method you should call `[self.myView removeFromSuperview]`.

Previous answer, before you added the rest of your code:

> From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Performance/Performance.html):
>
> > UIKit provides several ways to receive low-memory warnings, including the following:
> >
> > - Implement the `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` method of your application delegate.
> > - Override the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method in your custom `UIViewController` subclass.
> > - Register to receive the `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` notification.
>
> I don't see any of that in your code. So, unless you have other code where this is dealt with, simulating a memory warning won't have any effect with that code.
>
> Additionally, you are over-retaining both `photosThumb` and `photosFull`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView { 

    NSArray *_photosThumb; //the variables have _ prefix because then you can distinct them from properties
    NSArray *_photosFull;
    NSMutableArray *_photoItemsArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* photosThumb;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* photosFull;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* photoItemsArray;

@end

#import "MyScrollView.h"


@implementation MyScrollView

@synthesize photosThumb = _photosThumb; //when you call photosThumb from outside, it returns _photosThumb
@synthesize photosFull = _photosFull;
@synthesize photoItemsArray = _photoItemsArray;

-(id) initArraySmall:(NSArray*) _photos  
        initArrayBig:(NSArray*) _photosBig{

    _photosThumb = [[NSArray arrayWithArray: _photos] retain]; // retain > take ownership of the object
    _photosFull =  [[NSArray arrayWithArray: _photosBig] retain];

    NSUInteger i, count = [_photosThumb count];

    _photoItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {       
        UIButton* photoButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"MyButton 1: %d", [photoButton retainCount]);

        [photoButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(buttonDown: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        

        [_photoItemsArray addObject:photoButton];
        NSLog(@"MyButton 2: %d", [photoButton retainCount]);

        [photoButton release];
        NSLog(@"MyButton 3: %d", [photoButton retainCount]);

        [self addSubview:[_photoItemsArray lastObject]];   
        NSLog(@"MyButton 4: %d", [photoButton retainCount]);
    }

    NSLog(@"photosThumb: %d photosFull: %d", [_photosThumb retainCount], [_photosFull retainCount]);

    [_photoItemsArray removeAllObjects]; //this makes sure the array is empty
    [_photoItemsArray release]; // note: since this is a class variable you should put this in dealloc
    NSLog(@"photoItemsArray 1: %d", [_photoItemsArray retainCount]);

    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");

    [_photosThumb release]; //release what you "own"
    [_photosFull release];
    /*[_photoItemsArray removeAllObjects];
    [_photoItemsArray release];*/
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```